# Query the application name in nodejs

Tags: node.js

How can I access the `name` field from `package.json` at runtime?

Is that already stored somewhere or should I open and parse `package.json` myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not stored anywhere by default; the easiest way to load it is probably to just use `require`:

```
require(__dirname + '/package.json').name
```

Answer (score 10):

If you start your application with `npm`, a more robust & more simple approach consists in using  `process.env.npm_package_name`.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars for more information.